# If it's possible to change solidity code once deployed in ethereum blockchain

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain

I deployed solidity code in ethereum blockchain. Now my client ask to add some function in the deployed solidity code and need update that code in same contract address but i do no if it's possible or not.If any one know please answer the above question.

Comment: No. You can change the code once deployed.

Comment: could you help me out

Comment: Sure. Contact me on skype : prashant23061 . Let's see if I can be of help

Answer (score 1):

Once deployed, then the original code is final. 
Further upgrading of a smart contract becomes difficult as it would require that you've taken upgradeability patterns into consideration during your early contract architecting stage (e.g. you could use proxy contracts, libraries, or registry contracts to separate certain concerns from each other to allow for upgradeability mechanisms).